# Rearrage html table column in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

HTML table

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">1</th>
      <th class="text-center">3</th>
      <th class="text-center">2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody class="result_body">

</tbody>
```

data

```
var data = [
               {
                  "0": "1",
                  "1": "20"
               },                  
               {
                  "0": "2",
                  "1": "30"
               },
               {
                  "0": "3",
                  "1": "5"
               }
             ]
```

I create one table with th name 1,3,2, after that inside jquery I try to loop the data and append into the table. But it will follow the sequence with is 1,2,3. How can I append the data follow the table sequence with is 1,3,2?

Jquery Data output

```
<th>
  <td>20</td>
  <td>30</td>
  <td>5</td>
<th>
```

Data correct should be

```
<th>
  <td>20</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>30</td>
<th>
```

***code here***
https://jsfiddle.net/vwL0frhm/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate your headers, and find the corresponding value (instead to iterate the array):

```
$('#opt_head th').each(function(dkey, dvalue) {
      let textHeader =  $(dvalue).text();
      let value = data.find(o => o[0] === textHeader)[1];
      html += "<td>"+ value +"</td>";
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hansfelix50/Ltqvr3bm/